# With sbt accembly pkg, but still got Err "java.sql.SQLException: No suitable driver found for jdbc:mysql"

Tags: apache-spark

very simple scala script as below. Got err "java.sql.SQLException: No suitable driver found for jdbc:mysql:" after do spark-submit.

Use sbt assembly build artifact and i'm sure included mysql-connector-java driver.(Console output "established")

"java -cp SimpleApp.jar SimpleApp" it's worked

```
object SimpleApp {
  def main(args: Array[String]) {
    val dbc = "jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/test?user=root&password=123456"
    Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver")
    val conn = DriverManager.getConnection(dbc)
    println("established")
    conn.close()

    Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver")
    val config = new BoneCPConfig()
    config.setJdbcUrl("jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/test")
    config.setUsername("root")
    config.setPassword("******")
    try {
      val connPool = new BoneCP(config)
      val conn2 = connPool.getConnection()
      println("established from BoneCP")
      conn2.close()
      connPool.shutdown()
    } catch {
      case exception:Exception => {
        println(exception)
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: scalaVersion := "2.11.11"

libraryDependencies ++= Seq(
  "org.apache.spark" %% "spark-core" % "2.1.0",
  "com.jolbox" % "bonecp" % "0.8.0.RELEASE",
  "mysql" % "mysql-connector-java" % "5.1.41"
)

Comment: resolved by add --driver-class-path but not worked with --jars.

Comment: Yes, because this code is not using Spark ;) So everything is launched in driver